# Alternate to foreach() - PHP

Tags: php, foreach, fetchall

I'm trying to find an alternate to my method of fetching all data in a function for a specific user where their session equals their username.

***It was working fine until I moved hosting and now it throws errors. The following code is what I was using on my old hosting when it was working fine :***

```
$username = 'Benza';
$query = "SELECT id, username, password, email, ip, lastonline, rank, register_time FROM users_ WHERE username = '$username'";
$result = $con->query($query);
return $result->fetch_all();
```

It says : `Call to a member function fetch_all() on boolean`.

***And when I try something like :***

```
$username = 'Admin';
$query = "SELECT id, username, password, email, ip, lastonline, rank, 
register_time FROM users_ WHERE username = '$username'";
$result = $con->query($query);
$data = mysqli_fetch_all($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
return $data;
```

I get 
`Warning: mysqli_fetch_all() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`

***I'm calling my foreach functions as shown below (because the above code is in a function in the same class) :***

```
$users = $this->grabUserInfos($con);
foreach ($users as $user) {
    $username = $user[1];
    $email = $user[3];
}
```

Comment: $result = $con->query($query) or die($con->error);
What error do you see?

Comment: Thats because your query has failed. Fix that

Comment: ALso your script is at risk of [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: Is this really the table name `users_`??

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes why ?

Comment: Pasha, thanks man! It works now.

Comment: @RiggsFolly How could I go about doing this in a prepared statement using PDO then ?

Comment: @RiggsFolly Would this be better practise ? `$username = 'Admin';
        $res = $con->query("SELECT * FROM users_ WHERE username = '$username'");
        return $res;`

Comment: @Benza No, no variables in query. `$res = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM users_ WHERE username = ?");` then bind `$username` and execute. More reading http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php ...or you are using PDO??

Comment: @chris85 Great, except OP is using PDO

Comment: @RiggsFolly Perhaps not `$data = mysqli_fetch_all($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);` (Although since they asked about PDO it is strange)

Comment: @chris85 :) My fault for taking the OP's comment as gospel :) :) I should have applied the Dr House rule 1

Comment: @RiggsFolly So is this safe : https://jsfiddle.net/L6ntbtcn/ ?

Comment: Yes thats better

Comment: This question Needs Debugging Details.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that the part where the query is executed does not work anymore:

```
$result = $con->query($query);
```

The fact that you have an boolean in $result means that something went wrong with the query function. Because of that the fetch_all and the mysqli_fetch_all() function can not work correctly.

You should take a look at that part and find out why the query fails.